# Execute method before Business Logic

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I know about [Servlet Filters and Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm) but I'm not sure if that's what I need to use.

Let's say I have a method:

```
Integer count = 0;

public void increment() {
     count++;
}
```

and then a `doGet`:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

When performing a `Get` request for the first time, I'd expect `count=1` and not `count=0` because I want the method `increment()` to be executed first, before any other business logic in the web application.

Also, the count should be different for each user. It should be based on the number of requests a particular user has made.

What can I use to solve this problem?

*I would prefer to not use Spring or any other 3rd party library*

Comment: A filter is probably appropriate. Don't forget about concurrency issues.

Comment: Or aspect oriented programming

Comment: You **should not** add any field carelessly in your Servlet. A filter could solve this non-real-world problem. Please post more details about your real problem to get detailed advice.

Comment: Alternatively, you can make an `abstract` `HttpServlet` subclass which in the `service(..)` method first does some logic then delegates to the super implementation. Your custom servlet would extend from this one.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the problem I'm seeing here is maintaining state inside a Servlet which may bring concurrent modification problems. It would be better to check a better example about what OP's trying to accomplish before posting a possible answer.

Comment: Just a quick thought have you tried to make the Integer static so that it will not be iniitalized on each request. static Integer count = 0; I am not sure that the servlet is a singleton but I believe it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all depends on where the `count` should be available, but you can create an `abstract HttpServlet` sub class that calls some `abstract` method to perform logic before handling the request

```
public abstract class BaseServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // wrap it in try-catch if you need to
        prePerformLogic(req, resp);
        // call super implementation for delegation to appropriate handler
        super.service(req, resp);
    }

    protected abstract void prePerformLogic(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException;
}
```

Now your own `Servlet` implementation will extend from this class. You'll implement it as you see fit. But, [as Luiggi has stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232168/execute-method-before-business-logic/22232428#comment33759157_22232168), the example you've posted brings up many possible concurrency issues. A `Servlet` shouldn't normally have any mutable state.

If you just want to add an counter attribute to the `HttpSession`, synchronize on the `HttpSession`, check if an attribute exists. If it doesn't, add one starting at 0. If it does, increment it and add it back as an attribute. You might get better performance with a `AtomicInteger`, but you need to synchronized the check for the existence of the attribute.

A `Filter` would probably be more appropriate in that sense, since the `Servlet` wouldn't have any state anyway.

Comment: @ThreaT In the context of multithreading. If you get multiple requests with each accessing the same counter. If you don't handle synchronization correctly, you might lose updates to the counter.

Comment: @ThreaT Yes, only a single instance of your Servlet will be created by the Servlet container. Synchronizing correctly depends on your use case. I've explained how you could do it with your `counter` example. You should go through multithreading tutorials as it is very important that you understand concurrency if you're going to develop a web application.

Comment: @ThreaT The [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) to start. Then just follow the thread (no pun intended) for things you don't understand. Also, the javadoc.

Comment: @ThreaT In short, your `Servlet` is just an object. When the Servlet container receives an HTTP request, it will construct the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` object. It will then choose a `Thread` from its pool and submit a `Runnable` that simply does `yourServlet.service(request, response)`. There's more to it than this obviously, but that's a whole different matter you can look up for yourself.

Comment: @ThreaT note that synchronizing comes with a cost: creating a bottleneck for all the threads that try to pass on the same synchronization block of code, which is a **must-not-have** in web application development.

Comment: @ThreaT as I've said, it will depend on what you're trying to achieve. If is for simple curiosity, then I would recommend by not doing it, it's not worth it. If you have a requirement like do not allow pressing back button from browser for all requests, then use a Filter for the job. If you just happen to count how many times a user selected some option, update a database field, since the database already handles synchronization for you.

Comment: @ThreaT no, a Filter is like Servlet, it exists one instance per application context, and it won't be thread safe. Looks like you still don't understand that the solution is based on the specific problem you have.

Comment: @ThreaT no, I'm not saying that. I'm saying that you should analyze your real specific problem and decide if you really need to perform this method before the Servlet processing. If is as simple as that (despite if you really want to follow a decent design), use a Filter.